# Multiple CASE statements don't work when input value(s) are NULL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this SQL query:

```
SET @start_date = 'a timestamp at x in time';
SET @end_date = 'a timestamp at x + y in time';

SELECT DISTINCT u.user_id
FROM user_plan u
  JOIN user_feature uf ON uf.user_plan_id = u.id
WHERE uf.status IN ('PENDING_ACTIVE', 'PENDING_INACTIVE')
  AND (
    CASE
      WHEN @start_date IS NULL AND @end_date IS NULL THEN true
      WHEN @end_date IS NOT NULL AND @end_date >= u.created_at AND @start_date IS NULL THEN true
      WHEN @start_date IS NOT NULL AND @start_date <= u.created_at AND @end_date IS NULL THEN true
      WHEN @start_date IS NOT NULL AND @end_date IS NOT NULL AND u.created_at BETWEEN @start_date AND @end_date THEN true
      ELSE false
    END
  ) = true;
```

`start_date` and `end_date` are coming as input parameters. The issue is that they can be nullable, and so far the third and fourth `WHEN` statements are not working.

Is there any way to simplify this little madness? This is how far I could go with my flaky SQL skills.

Comment: It's generally a bad idea to use `case` expressions in `where` clauses. Use `AND`/`OR` instead!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `user_id` is unique in `user_plan`, I would go for:

```
SELECT u.user_id
FROM user_plan u
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM user_feature uf 
              WHERE uf.user_plan_id = u.id AND
                    uf.status IN ('PENDING_ACTIVE', 'PENDING_INACTIVE')
             ) AND
      (@end_date IS NULL OR @end_date >= u.created_at) AND
      (@start_date IS NULL OR @start_date <= u.created_at);
```

Even if `user_plan.user_id` is not null, you can still use this formulation with `select distinct`, but removing the `distinct` should be a notable performance improvement.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this query.

In your case you can use `OR` instead of `CASE WHEN` expressions

```
SELECT DISTINCT u.user_id
FROM user_plan u
  JOIN user_feature uf ON uf.user_plan_id = u.id
WHERE uf.status IN ('PENDING_ACTIVE', 'PENDING_INACTIVE')
  AND (
    (@start_date IS NULL AND @end_date IS NULL)
    OR
    (
        @end_date IS NOT NULL AND @end_date >= u.created_at
    )
    OR
    (   
        @start_date IS NOT NULL AND @start_date <= u.created_at
    )
    OR
    (   
        @start_date IS NOT NULL AND @end_date IS NOT NULL AND u.created_at BETWEEN @start_date AND @end_date
    )
  )
```

Comment: This query works perfectly also. The only reason I went for the other one from `Gordon Linoff` was performance. It works faster under Spring Data JPA, which is the underlying solution/technology I'm using in the end.